# Retrieving a HashMap LiveData via Room Library

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack, android-livedata

I have a social networking app which displays a list of users, and am looking to have an efficient way of being able to retrieve an object from my LiveData using its primary key.

**Example**: Retrieve a set of User POJOs from within my LiveData<List<User>> given a LIST of userId Integers (ie, users 12, 5, 7, and 1). I need to be able to look up these users by the userId for display in the appropriate order in the UI.

I believe I want something more like LiveData<**Map**<Integer, User>>, but how could I implement this using the Room database, without breaking the LiveData callbacks from my local DB -> Room -> LiveData -> UI?

**PROPOSAL 1**:

Change my Room implementation to somehow return a LiveData containing a HashMap of <userId,User>.

Current Room implementation:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in :userIds LIMIT 1")
LiveData<List<User>> getUsers(List<Integer> userIds);
```

Proposed Room implementation (no idea if something like this is possible or what it would even look like):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in :userIds LIMIT 1")
LiveData<**HashMap**<Integer,User>> getUsers(List<Integer> userIds);
```

**PROPOSAL 2**:

Have a list of many LiveData objects WITHIN a Map:

Map<Integer,LiveData<User>> liveDataUsers;

This might be something to look into, but I'm worried that having potentially hundreds/thousands of LiveData objects within a map is bad design and could also lead to performance issues / too many open LiveData internal callback threads.

**PROPOSAL 3**:

Something else??? I feel like I am missing something easy here. How are others looking up objects within their LiveData using only their primaryKey?

**edit**: this is something I'd like to achieve at the Repo / Model level and not at the activity level, as this LiveData will be re-used throughout the app.

Comment: "PROPOSAL 1" *might* be accomplished via a `TypeConverter` to convert between `List<User>` and `HashMap<Integer, User>`. However, both the `List` and the `HashMap` seem pointless, as you only have one user (`LIMIT 1`). Similarly, passing in `List<Integer>` seems pointless, as you only have one user. "How are others looking up objects within their LiveData using only their primaryKey?" -- `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :id`.

Comment: I should be more specific - the app will be displaying a LIST of users (ie, friends) and their associated profiles all at once. So I'd need to display the LiveData contents for say, userIds 1, 8, 7, and 3 in that order. If I retrieved a `LiveData<List>` from the DB, it's not very efficient at providing me a lookup mechanism of individual users by id.

Comment: If you actually are trying to get a collection of users, you would need to remove `LIMIT 1`. I don't know what you want the `HashMap` for, but you could [use `Transformations.map()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations.html#map(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E)). to convert the `List` into a `HashMap`.

Comment: "So I'd need to display the LiveData contents for say, userIds 1, 8, 7, and 3 in that order" -- then you would need some type of ordered collection, and a `HashMap` is not ordered.

Comment: I think I've derived a couple key points from your comments: 
**1)** the ordering should always take place in the query - not in the Activity - such that the Collection returned by Room query is ready-to-go in the UI
**2)** Don't try to use LiveData as a global cache of users for subsequent Activities/gestures from which we can poll via primaryKey - use the Room DB as the cache, and assume the LiveData contents matches ONLY the most recent query exactly (ie, may be replaced entirely be the next user gesture).
Correct?

Comment: "so the ordering should always take place in the query" -- I don't think that's possible, if you literally mean the SQL. "such that the Collection returned by Room query is ready-to-go in the UI? " -- well, you wrote that "this is something I'd like to achieve at the Repo / Model level". `Transformations.map()` would be something your repository would apply to the `LiveData` it gets from your Room DAO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the Transformations.map() as well